Firebird_ODBC 64-bit, library gds32.dll failed to load
I installed 64-bit 3.0.11 fbclient and gds32 using instclient on a new Windows server.
Then verified with isql that I could connect to a db on another server.
Installed 64-bit Firebird_ODBC 2.0.5.
Creating and testing a new DSN always gives error "library gds32.dll failed to load".

The C++ 2010 redistributable (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26999)
needs to be installed on the machine.
I installed both 64 and 32 bit. After this the DSN worked.
